# Превышен разрешенный размер

Tags: sql-server

Работаю на sql server 2008 r2  express edition.

> Ошибка базы данных превышен разрешенный предел в 10240 МБ на база
>   данных

Как решить?

Comment: Подели таблицы базы между двумя СУБД. А предел не победишь.

Comment: Если версия сервера не принципиальна, то установите Developer Edition 2014, который нынче дают бесплатно. Если принципиальна, тогда, как уже сказали, разбивать исходную базу на несколько, либо таки придется раскошеливаться на платную редакцию (вариант пиратства не рассматриваем).

Comment: Ну, бэкап-то не из воздуха материализовался, а создан на каком-то сервере. Вот на том сервере и надо модифицировать базу, чтобы уложиться в ограничение по размеру. После чего сделать новый бэкап и использовать его. Имеющийся у Вас сейчас бэкап вы на Express Edition использовать никак не сможете.

Comment: Этот бэкап - уже готовый. Нельзя изменить.

Comment: Тогда вариантов нет — Вам придется использовать не Express, а какую-то другую редакцию.

Comment: не подскажете какой память у Standart Edition ?

Comment: У 2008R2 Standard также ограничение 524 PB ([ссылка](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/cc645993%28v=sql.105%29.aspx))